# jquery show() не срабатывает послеr setTimeout() method

Tags: jquery, settimeout

У меня есть flex div, в котором лежат еще 3 div с разным количеством контента, которые при клике на кнопку смещаются `translateX(-100%)`. Для того, чтобы удерживать footer под контентом актуального слайда, мне нужно прятать контент предыдущего, но только после того, как он покинет viewport, для этого я использую setTimeout(), при достижении последнего слайда, весь контент возвращается к `translateX(0)`, но по какой-то причине скрытый контент не отображается.

```
let count = 0;
let services = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article'));
$('#services-prev').on('click',function(){
     if(count>0) {
       count--;
       $('.services-slide').css('transform',`translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
       $('#services-articles article').css('transform',`translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
       $('.services-item',services[count]).show();
     };
    });
   $('#services-next').on('click',function(){

    if(count<3) {

      count++;
      $('.services-slide').css('transform',`translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
      $('#services-articles article').css('transform',`translateX(-${count*100}%)`);
      setTimeout(function(){$('.services-item',services[count-1]).hide()},500);



    }
    if(count>=3){
      $('.services-item').show();
      count = 0;
      //$('.services-slide').appendTo($('.services-slider-container'));
      $('.services-slide').css('transform',`translateX(0)`);
      $('#services-articles article').css('transform',`translateX(0)`);


    }

   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var thisElement = $('.services-item',services[count-1]);
setTimeout(function () {
    thisElement.hide();
}, 500);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что каждый слайд имеет разную высоту из-за разницы в объеме контента, так что если лишь делать невидимым, то расстояние между актуальным слайдом и футером будет всегда равно высоте наиболее высокого слайда, что портит внешний вид

Comment: А полный код сможете скинуть?

Comment: к сожалению нет, но ошибка закралась именно в логику js. Если убрать setTimeout(), то проблемы не возникает, но результат косметически не верен, так что именно в нюансе реализации этого метода и кроется, как я полагаю, ошибка

Comment: обновил ответ на вопрос

Comment: спасибо, это помогло, только теперь на повторной прокрутке слайдера, контент последнего элемента не отображается, но с этим я разберусь, еще раз спасибо.